# Is there a plugin to retrieve Azure Devops Test plan test cases to Jira stories

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, jira, azure-devops

Tricentis qTest has a integration where in Jira tickets can be linked to the test cases in qTest and the associated test cases will be shown in the Jira ticket in a qTest section.

I'm trying to find out if there is a similar way to pull test cases from Azure Devops Test plan into a Jira ticket.

There are a lot of integration plugins for Jira and Azure Devops but they are in general for bi directional sync for other products in Azure Devops like workflows, Repos, Pipelines.

There doesn't seem to be one which specifically pulls Azure devops test cases to Jira.

Any help is much appreciated.